"matplotlibrc" is read at the "startup" of what?
According to matplotlibrc documentation, "The matplotlibrc is read at startup to configure Matplotlib." It didn't say the startup of what.  Can I assume that it means when matplotlib or subordinate packages are imported, e.g., import matplotlib.pyplot as plt?

The configuration file is read from .../matplotlib/__init__.py, that is sourced when you import matplotlib, that's one of the 1st things done in .../matplotlib/pyplot.py

@gboffi: Thanks.  Did you want to post that as the answer?  It may also help to reference this explanation of the fact that a package's init file also runs when a subpackage or module in the package is imported.

An answer is not a comment, I'd feel obliged to quote appropriately documentation and source code to clearly show what's going on. May I suggest that you answer your question?

I would take your suggestion, but I'm not sure where the information in your initial comment above came from.  It sounds reasonable, but I don't know what to cite for it.  I'm already citing the documentation in my posted question.  I could say that it seems like a reasonable interpretation, but that doesn't seem solid enough as an answer.  Maybe just see if someone can point to a more definitive source?

All the definitive information is in the source code, in …/python/site_packages/matplotlib/__init__.py

OK, I added what details I could sleuth.  I have to admit, however, that the trail gets dropped at function rc_params.  I can't find where rc_params is invoked.

When a matplotlib or a subpackage/module is loaded,
matplotlib/__init__.py runs (see
here).
Additionally, when pyplot loads, pyplot.py explicitly
executes import matplotlib.  So matplotlib/__init__.py
is assured to run.
In matplotlib/__init__.py, matplotlibrc is searched for
in function matplotlib_fname, which in turn is invoked
from function rc_params.  Unfortunately, this identifier
doesn't appear in any other *.py file in the matplotlib
folder other than font_manager.py.  However, it's
prevalence in matplotlib/__init__.py strongly suggests
that the matplotlibrc is read when matplotlib is loaded,
either explicitly or by loading a subpackage/module.
Thanks to gboffi for pointing out its presence in
matplotlib/__init__.py.
